# JavaScript- How to change multiple <td> background colors randomly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this page [Screenshot of my page ][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZ5fr.png and I want to change the background colors (randomly and let the colors change automatically) of every td of this table  when i click Demarrer button.
Or if it's impossible how can i let one color slide between all this td ( just like a game)
Will Appreciate any help.

```js
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}



// ****************
// give random color depending on group
// ****************

var color1;
var color2;
function animation1(){
   color1 = getRandomColor();
   color2 = getRandomColor();
  
}


// ****************
// give all a random color 
// ****************

function animation2(){
  $('td').each(giveBackground2);

  setTimeout(animation2, 250);
}

function giveBackground2(){
   $(this).find('div').css('background-color', getRandomColor());
}
```

```css
table, td {
    padding: 0;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

body {
 width: 624px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 line-height: 1;
}

.groupe1 {
 background-color:#B0090C;
 float: left;
 height: 35px;
 width: 35px;
}
.groupe2 {
 background-color:#F7F27F;
 float: left;
 height: 35px;
 width: 35px;
 }
 body button {
 border-radius: 10px;

}

.round-button {
    display:block;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    line-height:50px;
    border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:#f5f5f5;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#A40205;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 
}
.round-button:hover {
    background:#9E2C2E;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<html >
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="projet.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="projet.js"></script>
<script src="jQuery_v2.2.4.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<table >
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<button class="round-button"  onclick="animation2()">Start</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}


// ****************
// initial random coloring
// ****************

$('document').ready(function(){
  //animation2();
});

// ****************
// give random color depending on group
// ****************

var color1;
var color2;
function animation1(){
   color1 = getRandomColor();
   color2 = getRandomColor();
  $('td').each(giveBackground);
}

function giveBackground(){
   $(this).find('.groupe1').css('background-color', color1);
   $(this).find('.groupe2').css('background-color', color2);
}



// ****************
// give all a random color 
// ****************

function animation2(){
  $('td').each(giveBackground2);

  setTimeout(animation2, 2000);
}

function giveBackground2(){
   $(this).find('div').css('background-color', getRandomColor());
}
```

```css
#container table {
border: none;
margin: auto;
}


body {
width: 624px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.groupe1 {
background-color: #000000;
float: left;
height: 30px;
width: 30px;
}
.groupe2 {
background-color:#FFDE01;
float: left;
height: 30px;
width: 30px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<html >
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesprojet.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="scriptsprojet.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<table width="30" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe2"></div></td>
  <td><div class="groupe1"></div></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<button onclick="animation1()">Demarrer</button>
<button onclick="animation2()">Demarrer2</button>
</body>
</html>
```

To keep changing, add this line to the function:

```
setTimeout(animation2, 2000);
```

2000 = miliseconds.

Comment: plus one for you man. because you provide your answer using the provided tools....nice job. :)

Comment: **Thanks Man** But can you let the colors change automatically after first click on demarrer?

Comment: @BechirAhmed You mean like this?

Comment: No , i mean when i click the demarrer button for first time the colors begins to automatically change. Then  remain change automatically

Comment: @BechirAhmed done that please check if its what you meant, second button only.

Comment: Hi @randy , if i want to after a click on the start button, the color of the tiles change gradually  from left to right, then from top to bottom using a list of ten colors different. how can i do that ? you can run the code at top of the page i update it.

Comment: @randy i mean : change color gradually **one after one** from left to right ... if it's possible

Comment: @Bacha Would you mind opening another question for this, and provide the code you have so far? I don't have time to do this a.t.m. so let's hope others can help you out!